# Question about COUNT (CASE WHEN AS 1) Returns to 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week',occurred_at) AS week,
   COUNT (DISTINCT e.user_id) AS weekly_users,
   COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.device IN  ('macbook pro','lenovo thinkpad','macbook air','dell inspiron notebook',
      'asus chromebook','dell inspiron desktop','acer aspire notebook','hp pavilion desktop','acer aspire desktop','mac mini')
      THEN e.user_id ELSE NULL END) AS computer,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.device IN ('iphone 5','samsung galaxy s4','nexus 5','iphone 5s','iphone 4s','nokia lumia 635',
   'htc one','samsung galaxy note','amazon fire phone') THEN e.user_id ELSE NULL END) AS phone,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.device IN ('ipad air','nexus 7','ipad mini','nexus 10','kindle fire','windows surface',
    'samsumg galaxy tablet') THEN e.user_id ELSE NULL END) AS tablet
    from tutorial.yammer_events e
   WHERE occurred_at > '2014-04-28' 
   GROUP by 1
   ORDER by 1
```

I am wondering why if I change the then e.user_id to then 1, the whole query returns to 1 instead of the count number, I am a little confused with the logic here.

Comment: Is this really MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Because `COUNT(DISTINCT <expr>)` counts the number of *distinct* non-`NULL` values.

The value `1` is constant.  So there is only one value.  Hence it returns `1`.

If you use `COUNT(1)`, then it would count the number of rows.  However, this is more commonly written as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: My understanding is (CASE WHEN..... THEN 1) so it returns all the row that meet the case when condition to 1, and COUNT(1) is count how many 1s.

Comment: @WYG . . . `COUNT(<expr>)` counts non-`NULL` values.  If you have an `ELSE` clause all values would be non-`NULL`.  If you have no `ELSE`, then it counts the rows where the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `e.user_id` to `1`, then you should also change `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to `SUM(...)`.